# How do you achieve Material design components pre API 21?

Tags: android, material-design

Have (or when will) Google released a support package for Material Design such as an `android-support-v21.jar`?

Are their Styles/Drawables/Anims available somewhere within the android-sdk folder which can be used to simulate the z-axis background and animation effects without such a compatibility library?

Comment: Check This Video :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97SWYiRtF0Y

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT**

Google have released version 22 of the Android Support Library which contains many of the API 21 components which can be used down to API 7.

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

This includes Floating Action Buttons, RecyclerViews, SnackBars, Toolbars, CardViews (which are your one stop solution for elevation among all of your views) as well as CoordinatorLayouts (for the fancy collapsing ActionBars).

With this library it's more than possible to fake having an API 21 (although wrapping everything in CardViews can be tedious ;))

Good Luck!